# find all words ending in "ing" in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
def find_all_words_ending_in_ing
  words = ["bring", "finger", "drought", "singing", "bingo", "purposeful"]
  new_word = []
  # Your code goes here
  words.find_all do |word|
    if word.last(3) == "ing"
      new_word << word
    end
  end
  new_word
  #  expected return value is ["bring", "singing"]
end
```

The code needs to iterate through the items in the array and output the words ending with "ing"

I get this error:

```text
undefined method `last' for "bring":String (NoMethodError)
      if word.last(3) == "ing"
              ^^^^
```

Comment: `words.find_all {|w| w[-3..-1] == 'ing'}`

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear.  [The `String` class doesn't have a `last` method](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.2/String.html). You should browse the documentation to see the many methods it does provide.

Comment: It might be confusing that Ruby on Rails adds a [`String#last`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-last) method. But Ruby doesn't have such a method.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you use `#select` and `#end_with?` instead.

```
["bring", "finger", "drought", "singing", "bingo", "purposeful"].select { |s| 
  s.end_with? "ing" 
}
```

When executing *your* code, we see the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        7: from /usr/local/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        6: from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/irb-1.2.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        5: from (irb):31
        4: from (irb):23:in `find_all_words_ending_in_ing'
        3: from (irb):23:in `find_all'
        2: from (irb):23:in `each'
        1: from (irb):24:in `block in find_all_words_ending_in_ing'
NoMethodError (undefined method `last' for "bring":String)
```

If you look at the [documentation for the String class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html), there is not a `#last` method, which is exactly what the error is telling you.

However, [`#end_with?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) will take a string and check if that string is a suffix of the string you're calling the method on.

To disregard any trailing whitespace in the strings in your array, you may wish to use `#rstrip`.

```
["bring", "finger", "drought", "singing", "bingo", "purposeful"].select { |s| 
  s.rstrip.end_with? "ing" 
}
```

And if you don't care about case, then you can either lowercase the string:

```
["bring", "WING", "finger", "drought", "singing", "bingo", "purposeful"].select { |s| 
  s.rstrip.downcase.end_with? "ing" 
}
```

Or use a regular expression:

```
["bring", "WING", "finger", "drought", "singing", "bingo", "purposeful"].select { |s| 
  s =~ /ing\s*\Z/i
}
```

Or using the otherwise mentioned `#grep`:

```
["bring", "WING", "finger", "drought", "singing", "bingo", "purposeful"].grep(/ing\s*\Z/i)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're not afraid of regular expressions, there's a great tool for this job called [`grep`](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/enumerable#method-i-grep) which works a lot like<sup>1</sup> the command-line tool of the same name:

```
words.grep(/ing\z/)
```

Here `\z` means "end of string" in Ruby regexp notation.

--

<sup>1</sup> It also does way more than match strings as it leverages the `===` operator, so it is even more handy than you might think!

Comment: Readers: both `\Z` and `\z` match the end of the string, but `\Z` disregards any newline at the end of the string. For example, `["wing\n"].grep(/ing\Z/) #=> ["wing\n"]`, whereas `["wing\n"].grep(/ing\z/) #=> []`. It appears either `\z` or `\Z` could be used here as the array contains simply a list or words. grep is great!

Answer (score 1):

String has no `last()` method but
String has `end_with?` method.

Example:

```
words.select do |word|
  word.end_with? "ing"
end
```